# What is the best way to convert Brazilian Reais to number using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

As per question title, what is the best way to convert Brazilian Reais to Javascript number?

For example:

```
115.000.300,50 => 115000300.5
```

I want the opposite of what is answered on the question [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: Use this `+'115.000.300,50'.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/\,/g, '.');`

Comment: @jurgemaister I want the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var val = parseFloat("115.000.300,50".replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
```